# Create Issue type in JIRA using Atlassian plugin

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to create a custom issue type using the below code.

```
  IssueTypeManager itm = (IssueTypeManager) ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(IssueTypeManager.class);
  itm.createIssueType("issueType", "issueType", "https://jira.atlassian.com/images/atlassian-jira-logo-large.png");
```

I have included the following line in Atlassian-plugin.xml file

```
  <component-import key="IssueType" interface="com.atlassian.jira.config.IssueTypeManager" />
```

But it throws an error while running the test case. The error is "ComponentAccessor is not initialized"
Could you please help me ?
Thanks!

Comment: you can try to add IssueTypeManager as a parameter of your constructor in your module class - it should be automatically injected. I don't think you need atlassian-plugin.xml declaration

Comment: Can you post your complete class and plugin xml?